# How to mark cells using str.contains()

Tags: pandas

Working on cleaning up one excel document and one of the columns(df_i['Email']) contains email addresses and I need to mark (by adding a comment to a comments column) Gmail, and yahoo emails. I created the exclusion list, but for some reason, it works only if I specify the index of email to be excluded.

input

```
emails_to_exclude = ('@gmail', '@yahoo')
df_i['Comments'] = np.where(df_i['Email'].str.contains(emails_to_exclude[0] case = False),'to be deleted','')
print(df_i['Comments'])
```

output

```
0                  
1                  
2                  
3                  
4                  
5                  
6                  
7                  
8                  
9                  
10    to be deleted
11                 
12                 
13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `str.contains` cannot work with a list, you need to make use of regex (regular expressions) to join the values with an `OR` statement represented with a pipe `|`

for your example, please provide a sample of your data next time please :

```
df_i = pd.DataFrame({'Email' : ['john@yahoo.com','john@outlook.com','john@gmail.com']})
emails_to_exclude = ('@gmail', '@yahoo')

df_i.loc[df_i['Emails'].str.contains('|'.join(emails_to_exclude)),'comments'] = 'to be deleted'
print(df_i)
                 Emails       comments
0    john@yahoo.com  to be deleted
1  john@outlook.com            NaN
2    john@gmail.com  to be deleted
```

you can fill the `NaN` columns with white space as so :

`df_i['comments'].fillna('')`

Comment: Thanks! and sorry for not including a sample. It works when I try to exclude only these two domains, but now I've created a csv file with almost 4000 email domains to be excluded. And now it shows me an error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 14: invalid start byte". Do you know what could be a reason of working when I have only 2 domains to exclude but not working with a bigger list?

Comment: Solved by adding unicode escape - df_pe = pd.read_csv(public_emails, header=0, encoding = 'unicode_escape')

Comment: @RomanPolyanskiy awesome, if this was the accepted answer please green tick so this can be closed :) best of luck and welcome to Stackoverflow!